# Google vision detector limited capacity

Tags: android, performance, qr-code, google-vision, android-vision

I process QR codes with google-vision api, locally (my test device is galaxy s4). Why can I recognise only two, perhaps three at most at a time (during one frame), given more clearly visible in the viewport? Is it because my device allows only so many codes to be processed during a frame?
I tried lowering framerate to as low as 5 fps (in `CameraSource`), to no avail (and it seems it apparently doesn't obey it, as the preview is smooth). I haven't seen any setting related to this, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Barcode API does have a limit on the number of QR codes it can read within a single frame, as you've found. It has nothing to do with the quality of the image or the device.

Comment: and yeah, even dividing the whole frame into subframes doesn't help either. I will edit the question accordingly. Can you please provide some docs for it? I will accept it as the answer